# How to make separate forms for one model in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is it possible make different views for add new item and view item in Django admin. For example I make new form for add item, but now when I open edit view I need basic form from the model.

Comment: yes it is possible. readup on `ModelForms`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Do it like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):            
        if not obj:
            return MyModelCreateForm
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I declare my add_item form as attribute of ModelAdmin class form = NewForm. And when I open change_item I have two merged forms. How I can really separate these forms. And exlude and fields attributes should work normally.

Comment: In my given example if you set ModalAdmin atribute 'form' to something it will be used only on object edit page. On object creation MyModelCreateForm will be used. If you wont specify anything on form attribute, default ModelForm will be used.

Comment: This will not work in Django >= 3.8.